# Парсинг ответа с сервера в JSON Android

Tags: android, json

Получаю такую строку с сервера:

```
{
    "towns": [
        "{\"name\":\"Berlin\",\"id\":1}",
        "{\"name\":\"Munhen\",\"id\":3}",
        "{\"name\":\"Koln\",\"id\":4}",
        "{\"name\":\"Bremen\",\"id\":5}",
        "{\"name\":\"Shtetgard\",\"id\":6}",
        "{\"name\":\"Drezden\",\"id\":7}",
        "{\"name\":\"Bonn\",\"id\":8}",
        "{\"name\":\"Augsburg\",\"id\":9}",
        "{\"name\":\"Kil\",\"id\":10}",
        "{\"name\":\"Potsdam\",\"id\":13}",
        "{\"name\":\"Rüdersdorf\",\"id\":14}"
    ]
}
```

Начинаю разбирать его:

```
JSONObject townsObj = null;
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, towns);

            try {
                townsObj = new JSONObject(towns);

                JSONArray townsArray = townsObj.getJSONArray("towns");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, townsArray.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < townsArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = townsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id: " + obj .getString("id"));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "name: " + obj .getString("name"));

                    TOWNS_LIST.add(obj .getString("name"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Но получаю такую ошибку:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"name":"Berlin","id":1} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Почему так происходит? что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз, когда вижу ручной парсинг Json строки рука тянется к пистолету, вернее к [Google Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson):

```
public class Town {
   private String name;
   private int id;
}

Gson gson=new Gson();
Town[] towns=gson.fromJson(jsonString, Town[].class);
```

Comment: если json реально приходит такой, как в вопросе, то проблему так просто не решить. там же массив строк

Comment: И что что массив? В моем примере как раз массив и разбирается